# Change capitalization on placeholders in ICU translation based on word location in sentence

Tags: symfony, translation, icu

I'm using ICU translation in symfony (4.4.41) in the following setup:

I have 2 yml translation files.

rules-placeholder+intl-icu.en.yml :

```
supervisorPreferences:
  student:
    form:
      titles:
        supervisor:
          delete: "Delete {type} for {supervisor}?"
```

rules-placeholder+intl-icu.nl.yml:

```
supervisorPreferences:
  student:
    form:
      titles:
        supervisor:
          delete: "{type} verwijderen voor {supervisor}?"
```

The translation is triggered in php:

```
$formTitle = $this->translator->trans('supervisorPreferences.student.form.titles.supervisor.delete', ['type' => $translatedPreferenceType, 'supervisor' => $sdd->getLabel()], 'rules-placeholder');
```

Where {type} is resolved to something like 'Preference', 'Voorkeur', ...
and {supervisor} to something like 'Dr Hibbert', 'Dr Hartman', ...

As you can see the {type} placeholder moves to the front or middle of the sentence depending on the language.

```
The translated strings are e.g.: 

   Delete Preference for Dr Hibbert? 
   Voorkeur verwijderen voor Dr Hartman?
```

And the capitalization is wrong for the English translation.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation to handle this situation, but maybe I'm missing something?

Did anybody encounter the same problem/knows how to fix this?